# Why do you have to fill python input before suspending debugger?

Tags: python, debugging, input, pycharm, breakpoints

I debugging in PyCharm.

I insert a breakpoint at the line:

```
p_result = input('Who will win: ')
```

Now usually the debugger stops without executing the line where the breakpoint is. However this time I have to make an input before the thread is suspended.

Comment: if it bothers you, why not place the breakpoint a line earlier? Or do you just ask out of curiosity? The answer would probably speculative, unless some PyChar-Debugger-Coder has deeper insights...

Comment: Just checked with VS: it breaks and the console is not responsive - so I am unable to input anything until I continue the program flow... if I continue all the characters in the console are spammed in and I can hit more or enter. so the console unresponsiveness might be a console display-thingie

Comment: It is curiosity. I know I could make a breakpoint earlier, as well as I could fill up the input and nothing unwanted would happen. It just seems like strange behaviour.